# Windows phone 7: how to post tweet to twitter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter, rest-client

Currently i am working on sharing functionality from windows phone.

My purpose is to share the status of the user to Facebook and the Twitter from my windows phone App.

I completed the Facebook sharing successfully and now i m trying to share the status (120 Words tweet only) to twitter.

I completed the Authentication with Twitter account using [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Twitter%3a_OAuth_1.0_Authentication_using_Hammock).

When i try to post the tweet to the twitter account after am logged in to the account using this tweet button click event,

```
 private void btnPostTweet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
        {
            Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
            SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
            ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
            Token = this.accessToken,
            TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
            Version = "1.1"
        };

        var restClient = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = "https://api.twitter.com",
            HasElevatedPermissions = true
        };

        var restRequest = new RestRequest
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            Path = "/1.1/statuses/update.json",
            Method = WebMethod.Post
        };

  restRequest.AddParameter("status", Uri.EscapeDataString(txtTweetContent.Text));

        restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
 }
```

And in callback,

```
private void PostTweetRequestCallback(RestRequest request, RestResponse response, object obj)
    {
        string str = response.ToString();
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(AppSettings.TWEET_POSTED_SUCCESSFULLY);
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(AppSettings.TWEET_POST_ERR_UPDATE_LIMIT);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(AppSettings.TWEET_POST_ERR_FAILED);
            }
            txtTweetContent.Text = "";
        });
    }
```

it gives me error as

```
"Bad Authentication data", Code="215"
```

I've successfully registered my Application to twitter developer account and Received the Access Token keys before making this call.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Prajapati.. How you solve your problem. I am also struggling to get the user details from twitter. Can you help me to solve my problem?  [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762349/twitter-integration-in-windows-phone-7) .. Please need help from you.

Comment: Hi @Vijay.. Are you tried in Emulator or the Device ?

Comment: Emulator only. I don't have device. It's working fine in Emulator now. Is there any problem when we run in device??

Comment: yeah.. You have to check the device timing also.
Because the twitter API is works with the Date and time of device.
if the Date and time of device is not set to exact time with region then it will cause an error like "Failed to validate oAuth signature and token".

Comment: because i got that issue surprisingly. and when i set the exact time region then it works fine. i am shocked at that time that it works with my device timings and shows the error like not Valid OAuth. you can not expect this kind of small mistakes when the error occurred like that.
I hope you can understand what i mean to say.

Thanks

Comment: Oh.. Thank you Nikhil for the value information..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From analyzing your code its seems you have to change at below code block :

```
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
    {
        Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
        ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
        Token = this.accessToken,
        TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
        Version = "1.1"
    };
```

Change this :

```
 Version = "1.1" to Version="1.0"
```

Now your code will works smoothly, enjoy the day.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it will works only in emulator. but not in windows phone. when i will try to implement in my device, it will cause an error like "Failed to validate oAuth signature and token".
So, how can i resolve it. please help me.