# Twitter Integration In windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I want to get the user information from the twitter and show in windows phone 7. I found some examples for twitter integration.

[Link 1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Latest-Twitter-integration-a42e8bb6/view/Discussions)

[Link 2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Twitter-Sample-using-0dfcce61/view/Discussions)

But in this examples i can only login to the twitter. I can not post or can not get the user information. Can any one provide a sample application or links for windows phone 7 twitter integration.

After getting login i try like this:

```
 private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string newURL = string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.0/users/show.json?screen_name={0}", userScreenName);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_Navigated);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(newURL));
    }

    void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error ");
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Result==> " + e.Result);     
    }
```

But here i can not get the user information. Please help me to get the user information.

Thanks in advance.

Now i try like this:

```
public void GetTwitterDetail(string userScreenName)
    {
        var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
          {
              Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
              SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
              ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
              ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
              ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
              Token = this.accessToken,
              TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
              Version = "1.1",
          };

        var restClient = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = "https://api.twitter.com",
            HasElevatedPermissions = true
        };

        var restRequest = new RestRequest
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            Path = string.Format("/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name={0}",///1.1/users/show.json?screen_name={0}&include_entities=true
                userScreenName),
            Method = WebMethod.Get
        };
        restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(test));
    }

    private void test(RestRequest request, RestResponse response, object obj)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Content==> " + response.Content.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("StatusCode==> " + response.StatusCode);

        });

    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Please help me how to resolve my problem?

Comment: Btw, Win7 is about to go out of support.

Comment: It means that MS will not sell Windows phone 7 devices. MS will not issue updates either, security or otherwise. Usually this means that users would be likely to stop using such devices. The current stable Winphone version is 8.0 I think. I'm on 8.1 dev update 2 i think.

Comment: So even i can not get the user information's? But i can log in to twitter via my code. Why?

Comment: That stuff should work (at least as long as MS supports it). The question is valid I believe, just that you shouldn't be targeting a new app towards WinPhone7.

Comment: Hi @Vijay.  Are you tried in Emulator or the Device ?

Comment: Emulator Only.. I don't have device..!! :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the Solution..!!! :-)

```
public void GetTwitterDetail(string _userScreenName)
    {
        var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
          {
              Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
              SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
              ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
              ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
              ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
              Token = this.accessToken,
              TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
          };

        var restClient = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1",
            HasElevatedPermissions = true
        };

        var restRequest = new RestRequest
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            Path = string.Format("/users/show.json?screen_name={0}&include_entities=true", _userScreenName),
            Method = WebMethod.Get
        };

        restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(test));

    }

    private void test(RestRequest request, RestResponse response, object obj)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Content==> " + response.Content.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("StatusCode==> " + response.StatusCode);
        });
    }
```

Now i got the User's In formations..!!! 5 days struggling comes to end..!! Thanks to all..!!